# Unity2D: Enemy doesn't follow Player when in its radius

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

Hey Guys I've been having a problem lately that I cant seem to solve.

A sprite is supposed to roam around (as it does) while nothing is inside its radius, however if the player moves close to it the sprite should theoretically move towards it and stop roaming.

The sprite doesn't follow the player and cant even see its tag since I cant even see the contents of the "Collider2D[] hits".

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FireCultist : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveTimeSeconds;            //Time it will take object to move, in seconds.

    private float xMax = 10.0f; // The boundaries of the spawn area
    private float yMax = 10.0f;
    private float xMin = -10.0f; // The boundaries of the spawn area
    private float yMin = -10.0f;

    public int xDistanceRange; // The max distance you can move at one time
    public int yDistanceRange;

    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;         //The BoxCollider2D component attached to this object.
    private Rigidbody2D rb2D;                //The Rigidbody2D component attached to this object.
    private float inverseMoveTime;            //Used to make movement more efficient.
    public Vector2 start;
    public Vector2 end;
    public bool roam = true;
    public Collider2D[] hits;

    void Start()
    {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        inverseMoveTime = 1f / moveTimeSeconds;
        InvokeRepeating("RandomMove", 0.0f, 5.0f);

    }

    void Update()
    {
        Collider2D[] hits = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, 10); // returns all colliders within radius of enemy
        int i = 0;
        while(hits.Length > i)
        {
            Debug.Log("Sees");
            Debug.Log(hits[i]);
            i++;
        }
        followPlayer();

        if (roam)
        {
            Debug.Log("Roam");
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, end, inverseMoveTime * Time.deltaTime); //Random move to new position
        }
    }

    public void followPlayer()
    {

        foreach (Collider2D hit in hits)
        {

            if (hit.tag == "Player") // if the player is within a radius
            {
                Debug.Log("Chasing Player");
                transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, GameObject.Find("Prefabs/Player").GetComponent<Transform>().position, inverseMoveTime * Time.deltaTime); // chase player
                roam = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Continues");
                roam = true; // Continue RandomMove()
            }
        }
    }

    public void RandomMove() // gets random coordinates near enemy and moves there
    {
        float xDistance = Random.Range(-xDistanceRange, xDistanceRange); // check
        float yDistance = Random.Range(-yDistanceRange, yDistanceRange);// check

        if (xDistance < xMax && xDistance > xMin && yDistance < yMax && yDistance > yMin && roam == true) // If within boundaries of walking space
        {
            start = transform.position;
            end = start + new Vector2(xDistance, yDistance);

            Debug.Log("Roaming From : " + start + " To : " + end);
        }
    }
}
```

The roaming algorithm works however not too sure about the tag detection.

[The script belongs to this enemy object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le3WP.png)

[Player Object Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8yau.png)

Comment: Try `hit.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")`.

Comment: Unfortunately that did nothing. However now it actually shows that it sees a tag in the array since `hits` is displaying its contents

Comment: Is the position of your transform.position the top left of your sprite? If so, is it coming to within 10 pixels of your collidable player? What if you expand the radius out to 20 or 50 or more just to test?

Comment: Your code doesnt change behavior other than looping and debugging saying "Sees" if you are in a radius... it always runs followplayer, and it always runs randommove...

Comment: I changed it to 100 and still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are declaring a new `hits` variable during every update instead of using your class-level variable. This means the variable inside of `followPlayer()` will never be instantiated, and the information will not be passed between the two methods.

Try this:

```
void Update()
{
    hits = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, 10);
    //...
}
```

You might also consider attaching a trigger collider to the enemy which sends a notification when the player enters/exits the trigger instead of relying on `OverlapCircleAll()`

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
        roam = false;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
        roam = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice catch on the local `hits` variable

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately that didn't work. I also tried the `OnTriggerEnter2D` but that itself didnt work for some reason :/

Comment: If `OnTriggerEnter2D` isn't registering, it might be a good idea to check out [Unity's Collision action matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) and confirm that your collider setup will send trigger messages. Also make sure that your [collision layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) are set up properly.